# Ruby on Rails: session-based temporary files? or not session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, temporary-files

In my project I have file uploaded, validated and then user is asked for more input based on file content. The problem is that user can logout, lose internet connection, get hit by a bus, whatever... In the end orphaned file stays at server. Files are not that big to worry, but having a huge mess in tmp/ directory doesn't inspire me plus that opens a potential security risk (that is user doing a billion uploads and completely exhaust free space available to app).

My current solution is own implementation of session storage based on ActiveRecord::SessionStore: ActiveRecord descendant with `after_destroy` hook removing orphaned files, add here a sidetiq worker that cleans timed out session and it'll be working ok.

But this scenario has a big flaw: "remember me" that makes session permanent. Hence session is never destroyed (until user logs out manually) and files are not removed.

My questions are:
1. is there a better way to manage temporary files that are uploaded, but should be removed after processing / user logout / some timeout / ...?
2. is there a gem helping with that? I have my solution, but I'm not exactly sure it is implemented correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with defining a time limit for these temporary files, I would suggest using something like the [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem to sweep for files over a certain age daily/hourly and remove them. Without knowledge of exactly what you're  doing, it would seem like a good assumption that you could safely remove temp files that were more than a few days old.

You could define a method to remove temp files based on age, either at the class level if such a notion exists in your app, or perhaps even in the user model (or something more appropriate). Then, call this using Whenever, e.g.:

```
every 12.hours do
  runner "User.sweep_temp_files"       
end
```

Since you also want to explicitly remove temp files when the user logs out, you could define this sweep method to accept an age parameter, or something along those lines.